# Was st:ENT always meant to be a simulation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In many episodes we hear about "chef" but never see the character on screen. That's about the only clue I have, but I'm wondering if it was supposed to be a hint and whether the intention was for the show up always end as a holo deck simulation? If not, was there any reason that "chef" is never introduced?

Comment: _"Was st:ENT always meant to be a simulation?"_ and _"was there any reason that "chef" is never introduced?"_ feel like two very distinct questions that probably ought to be asked separately.

Comment: Also you're assuming that the whole show was a holodeck simulation. Even just the finale was a holodeck _recording_, not a simulation. Nothing implies that everything we see was not what really happened in-Universe.

Comment: It was supposed to be a fun little Easter egg thingie for fans. Unfortunately some took it very much the wrong way and the makers acknowledge that it wasn't handled especially well

Comment: @Valorum - maybe, but for me that episode was never holosim. I caught immediately what was the idea - in fact, I had to refresh my memory what episode of *TNG* it was tied to. And I never had any doubts the creators, using that plot vehicle, wanted to "legitimate" *ENT* by plugging it into *TNG*. Of course, they already did that in *ENT: Regeneration*, but it's never a bad idea to reinforce the message...